# Parsing csv line to Java objects

Tags: java, csv

I was wondering if someone here could help me, I can't find a solution for my problem and I have tried everything.

What I am trying to do is read and parse lines in a csv file into java objects and I have succeeded in doing that but after it reads all the lines it should insert the lines into the database but it only inserts the 1st line the entire time and I don't no why. When I do a print it shows that it is reading all the lines and placing them in the objects but as soon as I do the insert it wants to insert only the 1st line.

Please see my code below:

```
public boolean lineReader(File file){
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String line= "";
    String splitBy = ",";
    storeList = new ArrayList<StoreFile>();

    try {

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        while((line = br.readLine())!=null){
            line = line.replace('|', ',');
            //split on pipe ( | )
            String[] array = line.split(splitBy, 14);

            //Add values from csv to store object


            //Add values from csv to storeF objects
            StoreFile StoreF = new StoreFile();
            if (array[0].equals("H") || array[0].equals("T")) {
                return false;
            } else {
                StoreF.setRetailID(array[1].replaceAll("/", ""));
                StoreF.setChain(array[2].replaceAll("/",""));
                StoreF.setStoreID(array[3].replaceAll("/", ""));
                StoreF.setStoreName(array[4].replaceAll("/", ""));
                          StoreF.setAddress1(array[5].replaceAll("/", ""));
                          StoreF.setAddress2(array[6].replaceAll("/", ""));
                          StoreF.setAddress3(array[7].replaceAll("/", ""));
                          StoreF.setProvince(array[8].replaceAll("/", ""));
                          StoreF.setAddress4(array[9].replaceAll("/", ""));
                StoreF.setCountry(array[10].replaceAll("/", ""));
                          StoreF.setCurrency(array[11].replaceAll("/", ""));
                          StoreF.setAddress5(array[12].replaceAll("/", ""));                             
                StoreF.setTelNo(array[13].replaceAll("/", ""));

                //Add stores to list
                storeList.add(StoreF);

            }
        }              //print list stores in file

        printStoreList(storeList);
        executeStoredPro(storeList);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        nmtbatchservice.NMTBatchService2.LOG.error("An exception accoured:  " + ex.getMessage(), ex);

                                    //copy to error folder
                                    //email
    }
    return false;
  }

  public void printStoreList(List<StoreFile> storeListToPrint) {
       for(int i = 0; i <storeListToPrint.size();i++){
      System.out.println( storeListToPrint.get(i).getRetailID()
                          +  storeListToPrint.get(i).getChain()
                          +  storeListToPrint.get(i).getStoreID()
                          +  storeListToPrint.get(i).getStoreName()
                          +  storeListToPrint.get(i).getAddress1()
                          +  storeListToPrint.get(i).getAddress2()
                          +  storeListToPrint.get(i).getAddress3()
                          +  storeListToPrint.get(i).getProvince()
                          +  storeListToPrint.get(i).getAddress4()
                          +  storeListToPrint.get(i).getCountry()
                          +  storeListToPrint.get(i).getCurrency()
                          +  storeListToPrint.get(i).getAddress5()                           
                          +  storeListToPrint.get(i).getTelNo());
                        }
                      }

public void unzip(String source, String destination) {
    try {
        ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(source);
        zipFile.extractAll(destination);
        deleteStoreFile(source);
    } catch (ZipException ex) {
        nmtbatchservice.NMTBatchService2.LOG.error("Error unzipping file :  " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }
}

public void deleteStoreFile(String directory) {
    try {
        File file = new File(directory);
        file.delete();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        nmtbatchservice.NMTBatchService2.LOG.error("An exception accoured when trying to delete file " + directory + " : " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }
}


public void executeStoredPro(List<StoreFile> storeListToInsert) {
    Connection con = null;
    CallableStatement st = null;
    try {
        String connectionURL = MSSQLConnectionURL;
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver").newInstance();
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, MSSQLUsername, MSSQLPassword);
       for(int i = 0; i <storeListToInsert.size();i++){
        st = con.prepareCall( "IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tblPay@RetailStores WHERE StoreID = " + storeListToInsert.get(i).getStoreID() + " AND RetailID = "+ storeListToInsert.get(i).getRetailID() + ")" 
        + " UPDATE tblPay@RetailStores "
        + " SET RetailID = '" + storeListToInsert.get(i).getRetailID() + "',"  
        + " StoreID = '" + storeListToInsert.get(i).getStoreID()  + "',"
    + " StoreName = '" + storeListToInsert.get(i).getStoreName()  + "',"
    + " TestStore = 0,"
    + " Address1 = '" + storeListToInsert.get(i).getAddress1() + "',"
    + " Address2 = '" + storeListToInsert.get(i).getAddress2() + "',"  
    + " Address3 = '" + storeListToInsert.get(i).getAddress3() + "',"
    + " Address4 = '" + storeListToInsert.get(i).getAddress4()  + "'," 
    + " Address5 = '" + storeListToInsert.get(i).getAddress5() + "',"
    + " Province = '" + storeListToInsert.get(i).getProvince() + "',"
    + " TelNo = '" + storeListToInsert.get(i).getTelNo() + "',"
    + " Enabled = 1"   
        + " ELSE "        
        + " INSERT INTO tblPay@RetailStores ( [RetailID], [StoreID], [StoreName],  [TestStore], [Address1], [Address2],  [Address3],  [Address4], [Address5], [Province],  [TelNo] ,  [Enabled] ) "
        + " VALUES "        
        + "('" + storeListToInsert.get(i).getRetailID() + "',"  
        + "'"  + storeListToInsert.get(i).getStoreID()  + "',"
        + "'"  + storeListToInsert.get(i).getStoreName()  + "',"
        + "0,"
        + "'" + storeListToInsert.get(i).getAddress1() + "',"
        + "'" + storeListToInsert.get(i).getAddress2() + "',"    
        + "'" + storeListToInsert.get(i).getAddress3() + "',"
        + "'" + storeListToInsert.get(i).getAddress4()  + "',"   
        + "'" + storeListToInsert.get(i).getAddress5() + "',"   
        + "'" + storeListToInsert.get(i).getProvince() + "',"
        + "'" + storeListToInsert.get(i).getTelNo() + "',"
        + "1)"); 
        st.executeUpdate();

       }
        con.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        nmtbatchservice.NMTBatchService2.LOG.error("Error executing Stored proc with error : " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        nmtbatchservice.NMTBatchService2.mailingQueue.addToQueue(new Mail("support@nmt-it.co.za", "Service Email Error", "An error occurred during Store Import failed with error : " + ex.getMessage()));
    }
}
```

Any advise would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: I think your problem is poor formatting.

Comment: That's not his problem - that's our problem :P

Comment: Any reason for not using a dedicated CSV parsing library? CSV is not exactly trivial - not when you go past numbers and start trying to parse quoted strings such as addresses...

Comment: @alfasin: our problem is *his* problem at the end. I for one *refuse* to read code when it's a mess - or when no attempt has been made to minimize the problem...

Comment: The other problem is that you blindly copied this code without understanding it.

Comment: @thkala please google `":P" emoticon` :)

Comment: @HotLicks I started indenting it but the kids got in the way...

Comment: @alfasin: I saw it :-p. I just thought that by talking to you, it'd sound less rude to the OP than "I refuse to read your *mess*"...

Comment: @thkala in that case - we're all good! :)

Comment: Hmm, I can honestly say that even indented, this code does not seem much better to me. I'm starting to feel the *close* link calling to me...

Comment: @alfasin - I indented some of it, but it would take too much time to do correctly.

Comment: @HotLicks seems to me like you did a pretty decent job :)

Comment: Such code is always bad to read or to maintain, but however if by my answer, I allow someone to do better, then it's not so bad. I do hope he'll do better :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formatting aside, your code is wrong (I truncated the part of the query):

```
for(int i = 0; i <storeListToInsert.size();i++){
        st = con.prepareCall( "IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tblPay@RetailStores ...
        + "'" + storeListToInsert.get(i).getTelNo() + "',"
        + "1)"); 
        st.executeUpdate();

       }
```

Don't do a *classical for loop* while foreach exists and can be better to use, and even if you do a *classical for loop*, use local variables, eg:

```
for(int i = 0; i <storeListToInsert.size();i++){
  StoreFile item = storeListToInsert.get(i);
        st = con.prepareCall( "IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tblPay@RetailStores ...
        + "'" + item.getTelNo() + "',"
        + "1)"); 
        st.executeUpdate();

       }
```

Which could translate as:

```
for (StoreFile item : storeListToInsert) {
            st = con.prepareCall( "IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tblPay@RetailStores ...
            + "'" + item.getTelNo() + "',"
            + "1)"); 
            st.executeUpdate();

}
```

Now, the second problem is your [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html). A `PreparedStatement` allow reusing, which means you don't need to create `PreparedStatement` per item which is what you are doing.

Also, you need to close the statement otherwise, you will exhaust resources..

You must not create it in the for loop, but before, like this:

```
PreparedStatement st = null;
try {
  st = con.prepareCall( "IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tblPay@RetailStores ...
                  + "SET RetailID = :RetailID ,"
                  + "1)"); 
  for (StoreFile item : storeListToInsert) {
    st.setString(":RetailID", item.getRetailID());
    st.executeUpdate();   
  }
} finally {
  if (null != st) {st.close();}
}
```

In brief:

1. You need to close the `PreparedStatement` after usage, because it is a memory leak otherwise.
2. You need to rewrite your query using either named parameters, either positional parameter (like: `?` or `?1` for first parameter, and so on). I favor named parameters, but they are not always available. The example I linked all use positional parameters.
3. You need to set the value for each parameters in the for loop, and care about the type. I expected here that `getRetailID()` is a `String`, but it might be a `Long` in that case that would be `st.setLong`.
4. Your query is reusable, avoiding the need to reparse it/resend it to the SQL Server. You just send the parameter's values. Beside, you can also batch update.
5. A `PreparedStatement` for a statement that you generate (like you are doing) is overkill, and beside, it is missing SQL escapement to protect the String you inject to your query to avoid it being badly interpreted (aka SQL errors) or worst, to do what it was not intended for (like, even if it is far fetched, dropping the whole database, etc).
6. The `executeUpdate()` return the number of updated rows. You can check it to see if there was updates.

You can also use [Batch statement](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparedstatement-example-batch-update/), which can help performances.

And finally, you can use [opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) to parse common CSV files.

Comment: Yup. Well, I don't know all CSV parsing libraries :) But that's perhaps out of the scope of this question (since after all, it's about a query that don't update anything, the CSV parsing seems working...).

Comment: And yes, if only the `insert into table` part is wrong, then the question's title is invalid and misleading.

Comment: I upvoted this answer, but to be honest I would have stopped analyzing the problem the moment I saw an SQL statement being built from variable parts with string concatenation...

Comment: While all your comments are true, it doesn't answer the question `why` only the first line is inserted (a question which, given the current information, probably cannot be answered). Second, I'm all for using prepared statement, but you stresses the wrong reason (SQL injection is far fetched when he's reading a CSV file) and suppressed the important reason (reuse instead of reconstructing the query again and again). All that said, +1